# AngularJS directive - why do the browsers report DOM exceptions with this?

Tags: html, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive for handling binary file uploading. Here's a plunker using it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9qcKW5A6yq1hS8OuWTNK?p=preview

The idea is that the model is initialized by the controller with (initially) just the current filename - not the current data.

- If the user clicks on the link, the data will be downloaded to his machine.
- If the user clicks on the '-' button, both the filedata and the filename parts of the model will be set to undefined.
- If the user clicks on '+' and selects his own file, the model gets a new filename, as well as the data (in base64) of the file in question. Now if you do this, and look at your browser's console, you will find that in both Chrome and Firefox, there's a very weird error reported (from the bowels of Angular) about accessing things we are not allowed to. Firefox even says something specifically about security.

To stop the error from being reported, instead of assigning

```
model.filedata = values;
```

try

```
model.filedata = '';
```

...and indeed, the error goes away. This is very weird - it appears the browser is keeping some kind of state about the string of base64 data contained in 'values', and has an issue with Angular touching it in its internal watchers.

Is this a bug on my side, a bug on the Angular side, or a bug on the browser side?

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 15 of your script.js it says:

```
'       type="file" data-ng-model="model.filedata" />' +
```

ng-model establishes a two-way data binding between scope.model.filedata and the "value" of the input element. When you update model.filedata with ...

```
model.filedata = values;
```

... Angular tries to update the "value" of the input element and this fails.

I don't see why you need this ng-model on your input element. By removing it, your code works.

Comment: You are right! It was a left over from my previous attempts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is no bug.

The issue is that you bind a model to the file input. (*`data-ng-model="model.filedata"`*)

This means that angular will try to update the value of the file input once you change the `filedata`.

And no browser allows to programmatically set the value of file inputs for security reasons.
(*otherwise i could set the path to a local file on your system with passwords and force an upload to my server*)

Just remove the binding and it works as expected (***[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPdsd8pXYrXE2WSzNRW0?p=preview)***)

(*and most likely you meant to bind it to the `model.filename` and not the `model.filedata`, although it would produce the same exception..*)